# GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch and LinkedIn signout

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, linkedin-api

I have an issue with signing out from LinkedIn. I want to user see the LinkedIn sing in form with user name and password after performing signout method.

**SingIn method:**

```
NSURL *authorizeTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate"];
NSURL *accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken"];

GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *authViewControllerTouch = [[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:nil language:nil requestTokenURL:requestTokenURL authorizeTokenURL:authorizeTokenURL accessTokenURL:accessTokenURL authentication:authentication appServiceName:@"AppServiceName" delegate:self finishedSelector:@selector(linkedInAuthSelector:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

[authViewControllerTouch setBrowserCookiesURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.linkedin.com/"]];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:authViewControllerTouch];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Singout method:**

```
- (void) logout{
    [GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch removeParamsFromKeychainForName:@"AppServiceName"];
}
```

But, the next time I singin, OAuth misses step there I need to enter LinkedIn credentials.

The App requests login and password only if it is deleted and installed again.

Answer (score 1):

despite existens of [GTMOAuth clearBrowserCookies] method.
I manually remove all cookies with "linkedin" in domain in the singout method

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage;
cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies =  [cookieStorage cookies];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
    if ([cookie.domain rangeOfString:@"linkedin"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, Use the following code:

```
            // LinkedIn Cookie Purge
    let cookieStorage: HTTPCookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    if let cookies = cookieStorage.cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            if cookie.domain.contains("linkedin") {
                cookieStorage.deleteCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }
```